# How to add more threads when building?

Tags: memory, yocto, openembedded

When doing

`bitbake core-image-xxxx`

the build task will auto select 8 threads (since my CPU has 8 cores) to build the image.

My system has 72GB RAM, can I force `bitbake` to run with more threads?

Or any way to ask `bitbake` to use more RAM?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To increase threads usage:
You add following to your local.conf inside the build/conf directory. Replace x and y with your wanted configuration

```
PARALLEL_MAKE = "-j x"

BB_NUMBER_THREADS = "y"
```

`PARALLEL_MAKE` defines how many threads should be used when using make -j command during do_compile.

`BB_NUMBER_THREADS` defines number of threads for bitbake.

I do not know about increasing memory usage, if you want to increase the speed of the build you could to it with a ramdisk.
https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/create-ramdisk-linux

https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/speeding-up-build.html

Comment: Yocto project inks above are broken.  Here's an updated link:  https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/speeding-up-build.html