# How to limit memory usage in yocto bitbake?

Tags: yocto

When building some packages, I found OOM in dmesg.

The build process was killed and terminated.

Anyway to set up memory usage limitations?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way for me is to specify the number of concurrent tasks running when building with

```
$ BB_NUMBER_THREADS=2 bitbake <target>
```

Where `2` is the number of concurrent build processes running.

You can also set this in your `local.conf`. Here's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66489245/1025836) on the topic.

Comment: it looks can only limit threads, and can't specify memory limitation.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the parallel make jobs.

Set a PARALLEL_MAKE yout local.conf

```
PARALLEL_MAKE ?= "-j 1"
```